# Ubuntu does not detect RTX 3060 GPU

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, gpu

Since my laptop is equipped with dual GPU (AMD onboard graphics and an RTX 3060), it seems that the system can't even detect the 3060 chip, because when I use the `lspci | grep VGA` command, I only see the AMD GPU.

How can I solve this? thank you in advance

Comment: Alt 1: See if the onboard gfx can be turned off in BIOS/UEFI hardware setup. From your writing it seems to be stopping any subsequent GPU from initializing.

Comment: It's good to post what manufacturer and model of laptop, as well as the relevant output from lspci, and maybe `inxi -G` (or similar); also what exact distro you're using (`lsb_release -a`). That's a weird combo, AMD onboard with a Nvidia graphics module.

Comment: Look at your system startup logs (watch your system discover the hardware) with `sudo journalctl   -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this. By looking into the BIOS I found that only the AMD onboard graphics card (which cannot be disabled) is recognized, not the NVIDIA.

Thus I went to the website and updated the BIOS with a flash disk. This time, however, the BIOS shows the info of the RTX 3060 card instead of the AMD onboard. So I am now able to have my Ubuntu 22.04 detect the 3060 GPU.

Hopefully this experience will help those encountering the same weird situation. Thanks everyone for the comments.